# How to use sysocmgr.exe on windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have the following script to run:

```
;@ECHO OFF
;sysocmgr.exe /i:sysoc.inf /u:InstallMsmq.bat
;GOTO Finished

[Components]
msmq_Core = ON
msmq_LocalStorage = ON
msmq_ADIntegrated = OFF
msmq_TriggersService = OFF
msmq_HTTPSupport = OFF
msmq_RoutingSupport = OFF
msmq_MQDSService = OFF

;:Finished
```

When I try to run it on my Windows 7 Machine it fails with this error:

> 'sysocmgr.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I can't seem to find the sysocrmgr.exe file on my system.  Is there a way to make this "Go" under windows 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sysocmgr.exe` has been replaced in Windows Vista and upwards with `pkgmgr.exe`

You will have to change your script quite considerably to use it.  It uses an XML formatted file for unattended installations of windows features.

Microsoft TechNet has a section all about it:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749302%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: Alas! I did not write (and do not really understand) my script.  Changing it will be a large task.  Thanks for the heads up though.